# SVN - Tag\Branches Inner Structure

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, trunk

I have not fully understood the svn folder structure. 
I have this structure at the moment:

myrepo
_myproject
___trunk
___tags
___branches

I know the meaning of each svn folder. But i have not fully understood how should i correct use tags\branches:

Mode A: myrepo\myproject\tags\REL-1.0\trunk\"content of trunk"
Mode B: myrepo\myproject\tags\REL-1.0\"content of trunk"

Which one is the best ? And can be both achieved using svn copy command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use what you call Mode B:

```
svn copy http://svn.example.com/svn/repos/project/trunk \
    http://svn.example.com/svn/repos/project/branches/mybranch
```

and also

```
svn copy http://svn.example.com/svn/repos/project/trunk \
    http://svn.example.com/svn/repos/project/tags/REL-1.0
```